# How to explicitly instantiate/specialise a polymorphic Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I was wondering whether it is possible to explicitly instantiate/specialise a polymorphic function in Haskell? What I mean is, imagine I've a function like the following:

```
parseFile :: FromJSON a => FilePath -> IO Either String a
```

The structure into which it attempts to parse the file's contents will depend on the type of `a`. Now, I know it's possible to specify `a` by annotation:

```
parseFile myPath :: IO Either String MyType
```

What I was wondering was whether it's possible to specialise `parseFile` more explicitly, for instance with something like `(specialise parseFile MyType)` to turn it into `parseFile :: FilePath -> IO Either String MyType`

The reason I ask is that the method of annotation can become clumsy with larger functions. For instance, imagine `parseFile` gets called by `foo` which gets called by `bar`, and `bar`'s return value has a complex type like

```
:: FromJSON a => IO (([Int],String), (Int, String, Int), a, (Double, [String]))
```

This means that if I want to call bar with `a` as `MyType`, I have to annotate the call with

```
:: IO (([Int],String), (Int, String, Int), MyType, (Double, [String]))
```

If I want to call bar multiple times to process different types, I end up writing this annotation multiple times, which seems like unnecessary duplication.

```
res1 <- bar inputA :: IO (([Int],String), (Int, String, Int), MyType, (Double, [String]))
res2 <- bar inputB :: IO (([Int],String), (Int, String, Int), OtherType, (Double, [String]))
res3 <- bar inputC :: IO (([Int],String), (Int, String, Int), YetAnotherType, (Double, [String]))
```

Is there a way to avoid this? I'm aware it would be possible to bind the result of `bar inputA` and use it in a function expecting a `MyType`, allowing the type engine to infer that the `a` in question was a `MyType` without requiring explicit annotation. This seems to sacrifice type safety however, as if I accidentally used the result of the above `bar inputB` (an `OtherType`) in a function that expects a `MyType`, for instance, the type system wouldn't complain, instead the program would fail at runtime when attempting to parse `inputB` into a `MyType`, as `inputB` contains an `OtherType`, not a `MyType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a small correction, the type should be

```
parseFile :: FromJSON a => FilePath -> IO (Either String a)
```

The parenthesis are important and necessary

---

There are a couple ways around this.  For example, if you had a function

```
useMyType :: MyType -> IO ()
useMyType = undefined
```

Then you used `parseFile` as

```
main = do
    result <- parseFile "data.json"
    case result of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right mt -> useMyType mt
```

No extra type annotations are required, GHC can infer the type of `mt` by its use with `useMyType`.

---

Another way is to simply assign it to a concretely typed name:

```
parseMyTypeFromFile :: FilePath -> IO (Either String MyType)
parseMyTypeFromFile = parseFile

main = do
    result <- parseMyTypeFromFile "data.json"
    case result of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right mt -> useMyType mt
```

And where ever you use `parseMyTypeFromFile` no explicit annotation is necessary.  This is the same as a common practice for specifying the type of `read`:

```
readInt :: String -> Int
readInt = read
```

---

For solving the `bar` problem, if you have a type that complex I would at least suggest creating an alias for it, if not its own data type entirely, possibly with record fields and whatnot.  Something similar to

```
data BarType a = (([Int], String), (Int, String, Int), a, (Double, [String]))
```

Then you can write `bar` as

```
bar :: FromJSON a => InputType -> IO (BarType a)
bar input = implementation details
```

which makes `bar` nicer to read too.  Then you can just do

```
res1 <- bar inputA :: IO (BarType MyType)
res2 <- bar inputB :: IO (BarType OtherType)
res3 <- bar inputC :: IO (BarType YetAnotherType)
```

I would consider this perfectly clear and idiomatic Haskell, personally.  Not only is it immediately readable and clear what you're doing, but by having a name to refer to the complex type, you minimize the chance of typos, take advantage of IDE autocompletion, and can put documentation on the type itself to let others (and your future self) know what all those fields mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a polymorphic function provided elsewhere and given an explicit annotation into a more restricted version with the same name. But you *can* do something like:

```
  parseFileOfMyType :: FilePath -> IO Either String MyType
  parseFileOfMyType = parseFile
```

A surprising number of useful functions in various libraries are similar type-specific aliases of unassuming functions like `id`. Anyway, you should be able to make type-constrained versions of those examples using this technique.

Another solution to the verbosity problem would be to create type aliases:

```
type MyInputParse a = IO (([Int],String), (Int, String, Int), a, (Double, [String]))

res1 <- bar inputA :: MyInputParse MyType
res2 <- bar inputB :: MyInputParse OtherType
res3 <- bar inputC :: MyInputParse YetAnotherType
```

In the not-too-distant future, GHC will possibly be getting a mechanism to provide partial type signatures, which will let you leave some sort of hole in the type signature that inference will fill in while you make the part you're interested in specific. But it's not there yet.